# How to I scrape text from the first sub div tag which is under a Main div tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape text from the first div tag which is inturn under another div tag

The HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="main">
 <div>The text I want to extract</div>
 <div>The text I dont want to extract</div>
</div>
```

The code I'm using is:

```
result = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)


soup1 = BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")
name=soup1.find_all('div',attrs={'class': 'main'})
for div in name:
    print(div.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: you get list of div with class `main` but you need to find child of that div. so try with ```name.find_all('div')``` to get child list

Comment: If you have class or id for the div you can target using these else use like following
soup1.select('div > div')[0].get_text(strip=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your name variable you will get all div which have class named "main", then in your for loop you are currently looping through the collected div's, but you need to access the div's inside those div's(class : main)
so add a nested loop like:

```
for div in name:
    innerDivs= div.find_all("div")
        for idiv in innerDivs:
            print(idiv.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8"))
```